# How to use Android Internal Storage

Tags: java, android

I am writing an application where I would like to allow the created csv file to be used on a PC. Android has Internal Storage which is viewable on the Android and can be accessed via USB on the PC. I tried various methods to generate a file name:

```
/data/user/0/com.ed.ilan.ioioterbium/files/documents/2016_9_16_10_28_12.csv
/data/user/0/com.ed.ilan.ioioterbium/files/2016_9_16_10_35_57.csv
2016_9_16_10_46_34.csv
```

The name of the application I got using getFilesDir(), but the first 2 examples didn't work as Java complained about the slashes in the name. The 3rd one worked but nothing was visible in (appName)/files/. I don't know if this by design for security reasons, or if the file was really not there. The code is

```
String name = getFileName();
try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(name);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        osw.write("test1");
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Where I would really like the file to be would be in Internal Storage. I created a folder called myData, which I can see both on the phone and on the PC. The question is: how do I direct the application to write to Internal Storage. I recognize that this isn't "secure", but I just want to get the file.

To write to the Internal storage one needs this in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

If we should decide to put the file on a cloud server, is there a standard way to do that?

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using getFilesDir() then it returns a path which is specific to android application. User's simply can't access the path returned by getFilesDir().

If you have a rooted device then you can get access to the above path.

If you want that only your application can access files stored by you then use `getFilesDir()`, else you can use

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Still not there. For the path I get /storage/emulated/0/2016_9_16_16_20_46.csv. Then I get an error on openFileOutput as: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /storage/emulated/0/2016_9_16_16_20_46.csv contains a path separator. I think this error is complaining about the slashes.

Comment: The path separator came from not using new FileOutputStream. I edited the post with the correct code. Now I am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/2016_9_16_20_19_30.csv: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied). I thought the addition to the manifest should fix this but something is still wrong. Obviously the file itself doesn't exist, but it should create it? Maybe I have to explicitly put it in a directory like myData?

Comment: No go. It is something else java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/myData/2016_9_16_20_33_25.csv: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: On which android version you are running the app??

Comment: If you are using API 23 or above then you need to request permission at runtime

Comment: Thanks for the help. I finally managed to get it going by checkSelfPermission and requestPermissions in the code. I am using Android 6.0 and wouldn't have known there was a problem had I chosen to buy Android 5.1. More luck than brains....

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to write a file to your phone's `Documents` folder, am I right? If so, the following may be of help where you can write your .csv files at.

```
 Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
```

Comment: Still not there. See above.